# Httpcontext Does not contain the definition of a server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the following code

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
```

but it shows error on server that 
**Httpcontext Does not contain the defination of server** you are missing assembly or directive reference.

Comment: Where you are using this line of code?

Comment: I am using it to save the uploaded file on a folder.

Comment: Where do you use this? ≠ What are you using it for?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core by any chance?

Comment: yes  i am using asp.net core